# linux - can not view directory contents in text editor (coda), but can view in terminal

Tags: linux, visible, invisible, coda

I am using a linux machine hosted via Amazon's EC2.  Today, I moved all of the contents over to a larger hard drive.  I use Coda as my text editor.

Problem:  I can not view the contents of many of the directories inside my new data drive via Coda.  I can view all of the contents in these directories via Terminal.

Things I have tried:
- Checked to make sure permissions were set for said directories, sub-directories, and their contents.  These are all set to 775
- I moved the files to another directory via terminal and then moved them back to their original folder.  This allowed me to view the files and directories that I moved, but none of their sub-directories or files within these sub-directories.
- Refreshed all folders, quit out of Coda, deleted the site connection, and re-created it.  This did not change anything.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Weird....  I had changed all permission to 775 at once, but some of the directories were still set to 755, so I had to change these manually.